# Datatables not showing last row

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I'm using the jQuery datatables plugin to show a table, but the last row won't show, no matter how many rows I have. With `"bInfo": true`, it shows "Showing 1 to 10 of 11 entries" at the bottom, so it clearly knows there's another row. I tried enabling pagination, but while the next arrow was all lit up and everything, clicking it did nothing.

I'm 99% sure the problem isn't something to do with the item that would be in the last row, as when I add a new item with a name starting with 'Z' that became the missing one (they're in alphabetical order)

Here's my datatable initialization:

```
dataTable({
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                             { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': ["_all"] },
                             { 'sDefaultContent': "N/A", 'aTargets': [0,1,4,5,6,7] },
                             { 'sDefaultContent': 0, 'aTargets': [2,3,8,9,10] }
                         ],
            "bInfo":true,
            "sAjaxSource": Django.url('dash:testsets_header', testSetId),
            "bFilter": false,

            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": '<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i> Loading...',
                "sZeroRecords": "No Test Set loaded."
            },

            "aoColumns": [
             //Various column definitions
            ]
        });
```

Any idea why the last row wouldn't show up?

Comment: Fiddled around a bit more, and it looks like if I enable pagination I can set it to show all on one page, but not if I have pagination disabled, and I don't want pagination.

Comment: 1. looking at your other comments I'm kinda confused. Do you have 11 elements in your db? are you sending 11 objects or only 10? 2. Can you show me your view? how are you creating the json, the data etc.

Comment: @yuvi There are 11 elements in the DB, and only 10 are being sent via the JSON response. The datatable clearly knows there are 11, as it says "Showing 1 to 10 of 11 entries" at the bottom. The view in question is a simple DatatablesView. I feel like the problem must be in the JS (Or possibly a bug with the datatables plugin) because I can get all 11 entries to display if I enable pagination and manually set iDisplayLength to 11 or higher.

Comment: 1. what feature of linking datatables with the server-side code do you benefit from? 2. If you'd share your view I wll be able to help you a lot more

Comment: @yuvi I think I'm starting to see the problem. I'm using eztables for the serverside linking, but it looks like it wants to be paginated, much to my sadness.

Comment: What django version are you using? Also, would you like me to show you how to manually use django with dataTables? (which, I'll add, is my preferred way of integrating the two)

Comment: I'm in 1.6.1. I definitely won't say no if you want to show me how to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry for the time it took, I was busy with something else. My explanation is kinda general and not specifically related to your question (because I really can't tell what problem you're having with no insight to your server-side code), but I hope you'll find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not sharing your own code, and you mentioned using eztables, I thought I'd write a quick quide on how to integrate django and dataTables manually. It's a little more work, but I think the flexibility really pays off, and let's you define exactly what you want to use and what not.

Full disclosure: I hate generic views. As an extension of that, I also hate eztables and all auto-integration tools for django that prevent you from actually learning how to do something by yourself. That's just my opinion. That being said, integrating django with dataTables is not very complicated. It's just that dataTables sends a very specific XHR request, and you need to address it accordingly. The following is a rough translation of the code presented [here](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql). Alsom since as of Django 1.5, simplejson has been deprecated I will show you how to use json.

In my case, I created a model called `Item` which has only two fields - name and email. It's just a dummy model I created long ago which I spammed for testing. Then I wrote this basic-code for working with datatables. Note that the client side code is on another view (not the one returning the dataTables XHR request).

Here's the code, I'm gonna go over key points afterwards.

client-side:

```
<table id="example" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/datatables_view/"
  } );
} );
</script>
```

server-side:

```
import json
from cStringIO import StringIO

def datatables_view(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()

    # count total items:
    total = items.count()

    #filter
    search = request.GET['sSearch']
    qs = Q(name__contains=search) | Q(email__contains=search)
    itemes = items.filter(qs)


    # ... etc., all other filtering done here...


    # count items after filtering:
    total_filtered = items.count()


    # slice according to length sent by dataTables:
    start = int(request.GET['iDisplayStart'])
    length = int(request.GET['iDisplayLength'])
    items = items[start:(start+length)]

    response = {
        'aaData': [ [i.name, i.email] 
                        for i in items],
        'iTotalRecords': total,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords': total_filtered,
        'sEcho': request.GET['sEcho']
    }

    s = StringIO()
    json.dump(response, s)
    s.seek(0)
    return HttpResponse(s.read())
```

That might look frightening, but it shouldn't. Let's break it down (I'm only going to cover the basics, and you'll take it from here):

1. As I mentioned, dataTables sends a very specific XHR request. So all we're doing is returning an expected response in JSON. You can see a list of the parameters being sent and being expected to return [here](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side). You can also expend them and send your own stuff too back and forth, but for now let's ignore that.
2. So first of all, you need to return the data in json. I like using StringIO (or rather cStringIO which is faster), because when I initially used json.dumps it did all sorts of crazy bugs, I just got annoyed with it. With StringIO I never had a hitch so this is my normal approach ever since (though obviously isn't *the only* way to do it, and might not even be the best).
3. Always return the sEcho, it's just a saftey mechanizm of dataTables
4. iTotalRecords and iTotalDisplayRecords are pretty self-explanatory, they just return the number of total and after-filtering total (notice it comes before the slice)
5. you use iDisplayStart and iDisplayLength to calculate how much values you would show
6. aaData is a 2-Dimensional matrix of the actual data you are sending. each list should be in the same length of the colspan of the empty fillter td `<td colspan="2" class="dataTables_empty">`. In this case just name and email, but you can obviously expend it however you'd like
7. sSearch is the live-search input at the top of dataTables. you can use it to define how to filter (I just combined the `__contains` for both fields, but you can expend this and create your own logic, which is useful)
8. The example above *does not* show any trace of column-sorting. I'll let you figure that out yourself (not very complicated, [here's that link again](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) I gave you. Go ahead and check it out, see all the parameters that are sent to the server and what they represent).
9. Remember that any other implementation from now on is **on you**, and you won't have anything that works automatically. Every feature you'll have to configure yourself.

Like I said before, it might seem like a ton of work, but it isn't, and the flexibility really pays off. Good luck! Hope you find this helpful =]

**update**

The general examples for manual integration out there are truly lacking. I took the time to write a django-snippet here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3019/. It includes all common implementations (including sorting etc.) of dataTables in a very simplified format, including some admin-styled pre-defining (which is nice I think).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I waited to accept until I'd actually made sure this worked for me, but the datatable is looking good now.

Comment: Happy to have helped =]

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `"bPaginate" : false` since it is default set to true.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the code as it was when I was fiddling with it to try and make it work. I can get all the entries in one page with paginate on (Though not by default, it seems, unless I just hard code in a value I know will be more than the number of rows, since `"iDisplayLength":-1` doesn't seem to be working as it should be). When I set `"bPaginate" : false` I'm still getting only the first n-1 of n rows

Comment: remove iDisplayLength completely and then set bPaginate to false.

Comment: weird, I just looked in the datatables setup I use and it should work fine. can you post your JSON, maybe the problem is in there.

Comment: Like this?
`sEcho:1
iColumns:11
sColumns:
iDisplayStart:0
iDisplayLength:-1
mDataProp_0:name
mDataProp_1:notes
mDataProp_2:requests
mDataProp_3:trips
mDataProp_4:earliest_pickup
mDataProp_5:latest_pickup
mDataProp_6:earliest_dropoff
mDataProp_7:latest_dropoff
mDataProp_8:passengers
mDataProp_9:average_distance
mDataProp_10:average_duration
iSortCol_0:0
sSortDir_0:asc
iSortingCols:1
bSortable_0:false
bSortable_1:false
bSortable_2:false
bSortable_3:false
bSortable_4:false
bSortable_5:false
bSortable_6:false
bSortable_7:false
bSortable_8:false
bSortable_9:false
bSortable_10:false
_:1389715731159`

Comment: you are using it different than I am. I process my data server side and only pass all my rows in a JSON object back to datatables in one go. You still have iDisplayLength set in this object. I build an aaData JSON object server side and pass it on a click function via AJAX. It does nto contain anything but the data. My JSON looks like this: `{"aaData":["columnname":"columndata","columnname2":columndata2"]}`

Comment: I think your main problem relates to the php passing iDisplayLength set to -1, remove it from your php and it may work.

Comment: I'm using Django, not PhP (I probably should have tagged that). I may have sent you the wrong thing. My response has the same structure as what you mentioned, and iDisplayLength doesn't show up in that.

Comment: I am at a loss except to say you are only passing ten things in aaData - I would closely inspect you aaData object to see the 11 things and see if one of them is blank or something.

Comment: There are only 10 in the aaData, but I was operating under the assumption that this is because the Datatable has decided to only fetch all but the last item. The table makes it clear that it knows it's showing only the first 10 of 11 items, (or first 9 of 10 when I had only 10, etc)